# Changing the title on a Microsoft Access based form

Tags: ms-access

I've been playing with an order tracking system which was created by one of an ex-employee. Well, nothing major but just a simplified system. I manage to find most of the things re-linking to new database, editing layout... etc. However, what I am struggling to understand is as seen below;

[image]

As seen on the image **test 1** is the actual access file I have copied and made most of the changes to reflect **test 2**. However, as circled in red above (where test 1 is shown), is what I'm trying to find and edit. I'm not sure whether I'm searching correct terms but it seems I couldn't find any relative queries to fix this issue. Any advise will be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File->Options->Current Database->Application Title

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Didn't knew this was within the options. Sigh!

Comment: Just an addition, right below 'Application Title', you can add a custom icon take your branding a step farther.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Gene, but all I wanted was to change the application title. The rest I could review the tables, codes and see, as I just started playing with it.